# angular 5 form validation:

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I get this error on my angular 5 form:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AccountPage.html:56)
```

on the `name` variable.

I am using FormBuilder as you can see below.

It seems like I need a getter or there's a missing declaration?

Controller:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
...
export class AccountPage  implements OnInit {

    accountError: string;
    form: FormGroup;
...



 constructor(
        fb: FormBuilder,
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        private auth: AuthService,
        private afs: FirestoreService,
        private fcmProvider: FcmProvider,
    ) {

        console.log("%c constructor de account", "color: #bada55");
        this.form = fb.group({
            // name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), ])],
            // firstname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), ])],
            // add1: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), ])],
            // add2: ['', Validators.compose([])],
            // zip: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), NumberValidator.numeric, ])],
            // city: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), ])],
            // phone: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), ])],
            name: [null, [Validators.required]],
            firstname: [null, [Validators.required]],
            add1: [null, [Validators.required]],
            add2: '',
            zip: [null, [Validators.required]],
            city: [null, [Validators.required]],
            phone: [null, [Validators.required]],
        });
```

template:

```
 <div *ngIf="auth.authenticated">
    <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" [formGroup]="form">
      <ion-list inset>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nom" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <div *ngIf="form.name.invalid && (form.name.dirty || form.name.touched)" class="text-danger">
          <div *ngIf="form.name.errors.required">
            Entrez votre nom
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="form.name.errors.minlength">
            2 caractères minimum
          </div>
        </div>
```

**EDIT**
This seems to work:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nom" name="name" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].invalid && (form.controls['name'].dirty || form.controls['name'].touched)" class="text-danger">
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].errors.required">
        Entrez votre nom
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].errors.minlength">
        2 caractères minimum
      </div>
    </div>
```

With

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: new FormControl( null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), ]) ),
    });
```

but can't I avoid the heavy syntax: `form.controls['name']` in the template ?

Comment: Yes you would need getters to use it directly in the template or you can use `[formControl]` instead [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xxh7YMCoGn7JgUHdhW0J?p=preview) here has similar example

Comment: in your plunker, instead of this
̀
 
    this.usernameCtrl = this.formBuilder.control('username', Validators.required);
  
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: this.usernameCtrl,
    });
 ` Angular's doc show that this should be possible to do this 
 `
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username:  new FormControl('username', Validators.required);
    });
  }` isn't right ?

Comment: I updated my question with an almost working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

template:

```
   <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nom" name="name" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="text-danger">
      <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
        Entrez votre nom
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
        2 caractères minimum
      </div>
    </div>
```

controller:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class AccountPage  implements OnInit {

    accountError: string;
    form: FormGroup;
    name: FormControl;
    firstname: FormControl;
    add1: FormControl;
    add2: FormControl;
    zip: FormControl;
    city: FormControl;
    phone: FormControl;

 constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        private auth: AuthService,
        private afs: FirestoreService,
        private fcmProvider: FcmProvider,
    ) {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: new FormControl( null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), ]) ),
            firstname: new FormControl( null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), ]) ),
            add1: new FormControl( null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), ]) ),
            add2: '',
            zip: new FormControl( null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), NumberValidator.numeric, ]) ),
            city: new FormControl( null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), ]) ),
            phone: new FormControl( null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), ]) ),
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you `console.log(this.form)` inside of `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, you can see that `this.form` object does not contain attribute name. Each `control` inside of `FormGroup` is stored inside of controls attribute of object. So, you have to either declare variable that will point to this.form.controls or you can make check validity of form with `this.form.controls['name'].valid`

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the validity in your template with form.controls['name'].invalid